# How do I loop to keep making new object instances of a class?

Tags: java, loops, object

```
while (x < 6) {
    x = x-1;
    Dog kfl = new Dog();
}
```

Does this loop creates `6` new different objects and assigns them to reference variable `kfl` or ...?

Comment: The answer is yes... but this is a bad question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: x-1? While x<6? I think it won't iterate (if X>6) or it will run forever

Comment: Sort of.  It creates some new objects, but since there's only one reference, each object is "lost" once a new one is assigned.  So at the end you only have one reachable objects.  (Also I think you meant `x=x+1`, there's no initial value of x I can think of that will count down to make 6.)

Comment: I know it should be while (x>0) and x initialized as 6 before but coudn't edit a answer :S

@markspace yes can be written like that. what a day to make those kind of mistakes xD

Comment: Garbage collector have some things to do..

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Not forever, only until it overflows...

Comment: I know @Oleg. Was metaphorically speaking of course

Comment: There's no way to know how many times the loop iterates because you haven't said what the initial value of `x` is.

Comment: You can edit your question. You could also edit your answer, but you haven't written an answer.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs need reputation to have an "edit" function

Comment: @Krushe You can always edit your own question (unless it is locked by a moderator).

Comment: @ReinHenrichs now I see it, thanks! site design needs some improvements to be more "eye catching"  haha

Comment: @Krushe (OP) are you simply curious or is your goal to make a loop that keeps creating new objects? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Remember to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what x is. Also, the way you set up your loop, it will run infinitely if x starts at less than 6 or not execute if x starts at 6 or higher.

Assuming `int x = 0;`

```
while (x < 6) {
    x = x-1;
```

Should either by replaced with

```
int x = 6;
while (x > 0) {
    x--;
```

Or

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 6) {
    x++;
```

When you are defining the instance `kfl`, you *are* creating new objects, but they are all assigned to the same variable, so you are rewriting them.
If you want to assign instances with similar variables, a good way is to assign them to an array, and define a new instance for each element of the array. For example,

```
Dog dogs[] = new Array[5]; // Sets array to 5 elements total

for (int i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
    dogs[i] = new Dog();
}
```

The reason for loops are used here instead of while loops are that for loops are meant to be used for iteration. While loops are meant to be used as a continual conditional - like an if statement except constantly repeating. Hence, you would use a `while` loop when you don't know how many times a block of code should iterate and a `for` loop when you do know how many times.

Answer (score -1):

Object creation depends on the value of `x`. If the value of `x` is less then 6, then it will create an infinite number of objects. In the other case, if the value of `x` is greater then 6, then the loop will not execute, so the number of objects will be 0.

Comment: Could you at least add some interpunction to your post?

Comment: It is good that you are explaining why his code would not achieve the desired result. You should explain a possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

It will create around 5 + `Integer.MIN_VALUE` of `Dog` Objects. After each iteration they previous object will be eligible to be garbage collected. After the while loop all of the `Dog` objects will be no longer referenced because it will be out of scope.

This means in the end you will have no reference to any of the created `Dog` objects.

Edit: I took x as `x=5`. Since it has to be `< 6` to satisfy the while constraint.

Comment: Actually that depends on the initial value of x (which is not given).  If the initial value of x is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it will only create one object then exit.

Comment: actually, it will either create exactly 0 or infinite.... (while x<6 then x= x-1)  would need to be x += 1.....

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten It will not be *infinite*, because value of `x` will eventually underflow and become `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten How do you figure?  If you subtract one from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it becomes `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is at least greater than 6.

Comment: okok so infinite isn't the right word.. but... it got the point across.

Comment: @Andreas For the sake of complete correctness it will `overflow` Integers can't `underflow` though those terms are not set in stone.